# KOTLIN/FIREBASE Error when I try get data from firebase database - Client is offline

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

When i try get user information by his uid which is same like in firebase database this error is shown.

[image]

uid is passed in right way I have checked it. Route to database is good and I have checked this too.

Here is my code and this probably don't have any mistakes because everything work and only Firebase had some problems.

```
class Profil : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var fAuth: FirebaseAuth?=null
    private var database: DatabaseReference?=null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profil)

        fAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        // ✋ Here I checked with uid and uid.toString()

        var userCheck = fAuth!!.currentUser?.uid.toString()


        getData(userCheck)

        // ✋ Here I checked that good uid is get

        //tv_firsName.text = userCheck
    }

    private fun getData(userCheck: String) {

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
        database!!.child(userCheck).get().addOnSuccessListener{

            if(it.exists()){
                val firstName = it.child("firstName").value
                val lastName = it.child("lastName").value
                val position = it.child("position").value
                val email = it.child("email").value

                tv_Imie.text = firstName.toString()
                tv_Nazwisko.text = lastName.toString()
                tv_Stanowisko.text = position.toString()
                tv_Email.text = email.toString()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "User does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", it)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my database structure

[image]

I checked some ways to solve this problem.

I have seen some people propose a solution with `addValueEventListener`, but then the list is fetched. I want single user information to be included in my textViews. I read that the problem may be related to a bug in Firebase and not in the code.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Besides that, are you sure you have internet connectivity?

Comment: If `get()` isn't working, I recommend using the older `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` method. Both (should) return the exact same data, so that won't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem was with Firebase not my application. I don't know why but when I started app in every try  Firebase closed my connection with database. I tried add to google.services.json some links to database and change some settings but this didn't work. After all I removed app from firebase and delete file google.services.json. I added app again on website then I connect app with firebase and new google.services.json was set. That's all everything is working thanks for help.